# Keep an NSThread containing an NSTimer around indefinitely? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsthread

I have some web service data in my app that needs to be updated every 3 minutes.
I had tried out a few approaches but got a really good piece of advise in here last week, I should not build a new thread every 3 minutes and then subsequently try and dealloc and synchronize all the different parts so that I avoided memory bug. Instead I should have a "worker thread" that was always running, but only did actual work when I asked it too (every 3 minutes).

As my small POC works now, I spawn a new thread in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`
method. I do this like so:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateModel) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void) updateModel {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    BackgroundUpdate *update = [[BackgroundUpdate alloc] initWithTimerInterval:180];
    [update release];
    [pool release];
}
```

Ok, this inits the "BackgroundUpdate" object with the update interval in seconds. Inside the updater it is simply like this for now:

```
@implementation BackgroundUpdate

- (id) initWithTimerInterval:(NSInteger) secondsBetweenUpdates {

    if(self = [super init]) {

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secondsBetweenUpdates 
                                        target:self 
                                        selector:@selector(testIfUpdateNeeded) 
                                        userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) testIfUpdateNeeded {

    NSLog(@"Im contemplating an update...");

}
```

I have never used threads like this before. I has always been "setup autoReleasePool, do work, get your autoReleasePool drained, and goodbye".

My problem is that as soon as the `initWithTimerInterval` has run, the `NSThread` is done, it therefore returns to the updateModel method and has its pool drained. I guess it has to do with the NSTimer having it's own thread/runloop? I would like for the thread to keep having the `testIfUpdateNeeded` method run every 3 minutes.

**So how will I keep this NSThread alive for the entire duration of my app?**

Thank You for any help/advice given:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close. All you need to do now is start the run loop running so the thread doesn't exit and the timer runs.  After your call to initWithTimerInterval:, just call

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

The thread will run its run loop indefinitely and your timer will work.

Comment: Thank You Ken, exactly:)
It now ticks along and when the timer fires I get my model updated:)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want an [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-1173) instead of an old fashion thread. You could active the operation via a universal timer then it would execute on its own thread and then clean up its own memory when done.

Comment: Thanks TechZen. I read parts of the guide you linked to and learned something new:) They however don't recommend NSOperation for repetitive tasks, but rather for queuing an arbitrary set of tasks that has dependencies. Why it is not just the "Thread in a box" solution, however, I cant say. It did sound very promising at first:)

Comment: Okay, I missed that. Good to know.